# Contact Form Handler directs to blank php instead of html page

Tags: php, html, forms, contacts

I have a contact form which is suppose to go to a thank you html page. The email is being sent to my account BUT when submitting the page it goes to a  blank php page instead of going to my thank you html page. Any suggestions? The code is be low.

```
<?php 
$errors = '';
$myemail = 'yourname@website.com';//<-----Put Your email address here.
if(empty($_POST['name'])  || 
   empty($_POST['email']) || 
   empty($_POST['message']))
{
    $errors .= "\n Error: all fields are required";
}

$name = $_POST['name']; 
$email_address = $_POST['email']; 
$message = $_POST['message']; 

if (!preg_match(
"/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i", 
$email_address))
{
    $errors .= "\n Error: Invalid email address";
}

if( empty($errors))
{
    $to = $myemail; 
    $email_subject = "Contact form submission: $name";
    $email_body = "You have received a new message. ".
    " Here are the details:\n Name: $name \n Email: $email_address \n Message \n $message"; 

    $headers = "From: $myemail\n"; 
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";

    mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
    //redirect to the 'thank you' page
    header('Location: contact-form-thank-you.html');
} 
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 
<html>
<head>
    <title>Contact form handler</title>
</head>

<body>
<!-- This page is displayed only if there is some error -->
<?php
echo nl2br($errors);
?>


</body>
```

Comment: You can't have an `echo` AND a `Header` at the same time. As Alex stated below, use his suggestion and get rid of the echo. You may probably use your error message in an `if` statement.

Comment: You should also post your `form` itself instead of just the `echo nl2br($errors);`. Chances are you won't need that, because it's already in your handler.

Comment: I appreciate your replies. I was wondering if I could include the code for the html thank you page within the php? I didn't construct this code so I'm still trying to figure things out. I'm not sure if doing that will interfere with the mail being sent to my account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had problems before when redirecting to another page while something is `echo()`'d. Maybe this can solve your problem.

```
header('Location: page.html');
exit();
```

Comment: Alright, so I uploaded the site live and it's redirecting to the html page now  BUT it's not being found. I'm going to play around with it and get it work. When I click it it showing it in the forms folder but the page is in the root folder.It's not 100% but your response has helped. I appreciate both of you guys fast responses.

Comment: @K.H. You can specify a file from the root folder with a `/` like so: `Location: /page.html` or even relative to its parent `../` folder `Location: ../page.html`

Comment: @K.H. Try using double quotes `"` for your Location file. I've had a similar problem before.

Comment: Fixed it by adding a period in front of the backslash. ie: Location: ./page.html. And I moved the php and contact form in the same folder.

Comment: @K.H. Then you don't need the dot.  `./page.html` is exactly the same as `page.html`. Moving the file solved your problem ;)